# Pagination in Android using JSON data but without page number as a parameter in API

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to load the JSON data coming from server without page number as a parameter but I am not able to do that. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you not query the server via the parameter you want and filter by it?

Comment: Can I get any reference

Comment: Depends how the data if formatted and what server technology you are using. But in essence yes if you have 5 fields in your json you can query by any of these fields to return the results which are true(match query)